# AWS Site-to-Site VPN logging not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn

Anyone encountered a problem where logging to CloudWatch for Site-To-Site VPN isn't working even though logging is enabled?

The only log file that is created is one with the title "log_stream_created_by_aws_to_validate_log_delivery_subscriptions" and content "Permissions are set correctly to allow AWS CloudWatch Logs to write into your logs while creating a subscription.". No other logs are created or written, so I am unable to debug VPN connection. Any ideas?

Comment: I remember that it is fiddly to get working, but I've only enabled VPN logging once. From memory you have to set it up when you create the VPN connection, you can't add it later. Perhaps you could post your VPC settings, particularly around logging, for people to look at.